# How to rearrange array based upon index array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm looking for a one line solution that would help me do the following.

Suppose I have

```
array = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])
```

I'd like to rearrange it based upon an input ordering. If there were a numpy function called `arrange`, it would do the following:

```
newarray = np.arrange(array, [1, 0, 3, 4, 2])
print newarray

    [20, 10, 40, 50, 30]
```

Formally, if the array to be reordered is m x n, and the "index" array is 1 x n, the ordering would be determined by the array called "index".

Does numpy have a function like this?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can simply use your "index" list directly, as, well, an index array:

```
>>> arr = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])
>>> idx = [1, 0, 3, 4, 2]
>>> arr[idx]
array([20, 10, 40, 50, 30])
```

It tends to be much faster if `idx` is already an `ndarray` and not a `list`, even though it'll work either way:

```
>>> %timeit arr[idx]
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.11 µs per loop
>>> ai = np.array(idx)
>>> %timeit arr[ai]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 296 ns per loop
```

Comment: Thanks! What if the "index" is 2d array? For example I want to turn `[[1,2], ["a", "b"]` into `[[2,1], ["a", "b"]]` by using the index `[[1,0], [0,1]]`. I know an ugly way to do is using for-loop to re-arrange each row of the array using the corresponding row of index array. But there gotta be a faster way.

Comment: Note: the indexing array `idx` can not be a tuple. This was somehow counter-intuitive, but your solution works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: I know this is old but I am looking for the same solution. The line arr[ai] seems to have no effect at all. python version 3.7.3

Comment: Check [Dong Dong Justin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64638032/7058363) for those who it isn't working. I had to convert It using `np.argsort()`

Comment: @Skywalker326 I know it's old, but have you figured that out yet lol? I can't get the 2d works just like that

Answer (score 9):

for those whose index is 2d array, you can use map function.
Here is an example:

```
a = np.random.randn(3, 3)
print(a)
print(np.argsort(a))

print(np.array(list(map(lambda x, y: y[x], np.argsort(a), a))))
```

the output is

```
[[-1.42167035  0.62520498  2.02054623]
 [-0.17966393 -0.01561566  0.24480554]
 [ 1.10568543  0.00298402 -0.71397599]]
[[0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]
 [2 1 0]]
[[-1.42167035  0.62520498  2.02054623]
 [-0.17966393 -0.01561566  0.24480554]
 [-0.71397599  0.00298402  1.10568543]]
```

Answer (score 9):

For those who have the same confusion, I am actually looking for a slightly different version of "rearrange array based upon index". In my situation, the index array is indexing the target array instead of the source array. In other words, I am try to rearrange an array based on its position in the new array.

In this case, simply apply an `argsort` before indexing. E.g.

```
>>> arr = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])
>>> idx = [1, 0, 3, 4, 2]
>>> arr[np.argsort(idx)]
array([20, 10, 50, 30, 40])
```

Note the difference between this result and the desired result by op.

One can verify back and forth

```
>>> arr[np.argsort(idx)][idx] == arr
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True])
>>> arr[idx][np.argsort(idx)] == arr
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort it but descending:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
np.argsort(a)
> array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
np.argsort(-a)
> array([4, 3, 2, 1, 0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Numpy has a feature called [Integer Array Indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/1.26/user/basics.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) that makes this easy:

```
array = np.array([10,20,30,40,50])
print(array)
ind = np.array([1,0,3,4,2])
print(ind)
newarray = array[ind]
print(newarray)
[10 20 30 40 50]
[1 0 3 4 2]
[20 10 40 50 30]
```

Use an index array as the starting element.

Also works for multi-dimensional arrays:

```
array = np.array([[10,20,30,40,50],[60,70,80,90,100]])
print(array)
ind = np.array([1,0,3,4,2])
print(ind)
newarray = array[:, ind]
print(newarray)
[[ 10  20  30  40  50]
 [ 60  70  80  90 100]]
[1 0 3 4 2]
[[ 20  10  40  50  30]
 [ 70  60  90 100  80]]
```

This reorders by column.