# how to change the order inside channel in a 4D array in numpy

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have an array with the shape of `TxCxHxW`, how can I change the order inside a channel.

For example, I have `a` and like to change it so I get `b` as following (please note that it is just an example, in general, I am looking for a way fast to change the order inside the channel, The change of order is **not** random and we always have the pattern):

```
a = np.arange(48).reshape(4,3,2,2)
b = np.zeros_like(a)
```

```
b[0,:,:,:] =a[1,:,:,:]
b[1,:,:,:] =a[3,:,:,:]
b[2,:,:,:] =a[0,:,:,:]
b[3,:,:,:] =a[2,:,:,:]
```

Comment: How do you want to change the order though. If you want to randomly shuffle, you could use `np.random.shuffle` or other way would be to create a  1-D np array of indices and just do `b = a[required_indices_arr]`.

Comment: it is not random, I always have a pattern. can you say how you can do it for my example.

Comment: So, what's **the pattern** for a generic case with n elements?

Comment: let say the pattern is what I showed in the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the same result as your code, you can do something like:

```
a = np.arange(48).reshape(4,3,2,2)
b = a[[1,3,0,2], :, :]
```

Comment: is this the fastest way?

Comment: Take a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26194389/how-to-rearrange-array-based-upon-index-array

Answer (score 1):

You may need this: note:second row([0, -2, -1, -3]) is the distance between original dimension of target dimension

```
# convert numpy matrix dimension [N, H, W, C] -> [N, C, H, W]
np_train_samples = np.moveaxis(np_train_samples, [0, 1, 2, 3],
                                   [0, -2, -1, -3])
```