# Rearranging 2D numpy array by 2D row and column arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have tried to find a similar question but so far it seems only half my question can be answered.

I have a 2D numpy array, e.g.:

```
a= np.array([[6, 4, 5],
             [4, 7, 8],
             [2, 8, 9]])
```

And i also have 2 further numpy arrays, indicating the rows, and columns where i would like to rearrange (or not):

```
rows= np.array([[0, 0, 0],
                [1, 0, 1],
                [2, 2, 2]])

cols= np.array([[0, 1, 2],
                [0, 0, 2],
                [0, 1, 2]])
```

now i would like to rearrange the array "a" based on these indices, so that the result is:

```
result= np.array([[6, 4, 5],
                  [4, 6, 8],
                  [2, 8, 9]])
```

Doing this only for columns or only for rows is easy, e.g. see this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26194389/how-to-rearrange-array-based-upon-index-array):

```
np.array(list(map(lambda x, y: y[x], cols, a)))
```

Comment: Believe it or not, you can simply write `a[rows, cols]` :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical case of [fancy/array indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing):

```
result = a[rows, cols]
```

Output:

```
array([[6, 4, 5],
       [4, 6, 8],
       [2, 8, 9]])
```

Comment: so simple- so great...

Comment: @SamuelMüller indeed :)